# Different header image 'Home' and Pages

Tags: custom-header, header-image

I want to use two images in the header. In the home page and single.php is the image I've uploaded in the panel (named logo.png). For pages I want use the image 'logopage.png' (directory: /images/logopage.png).

Just the image I'm using in home page is working. In the pages nothing appears.

How can I do that?

Ps.: The code I'm trying to use:

function.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
  'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png',
  'random-default'         => false,
  'width'                  => 1050,
  'height'                 => 100,
  'flex-height'            => true,
  'flex-width'             => true,
  'default-text-color'     => '',
  'header-text'            => false,
  'uploads'                => true,
  'wp-head-callback'       => '',
  'admin-head-callback'    => '',
  'admin-preview-callback' => '',
));
```

In the header.php:

```
  <?php
  if ( is_home() ) echo theme_heading();
  if ( is_single() ) echo theme_heading();
      elseif ( is_page() ) get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logopage.png';
  ?>
```

Sorry my english :X

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using a theme created by myself.

Comment: looks like you are missing an echo for the is_page() condition

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
<?php if (  (is_home()) || (is_single())  ) { ?>
<?php echo theme_heading(); ?>
<?php } elseif (is_page()) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/logopage.png" />
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Link to the source of the code please.

Comment: I just tried different ways, and I came to this result alone.